# The Order of the elements in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is an group with identity element $e$. Am I correct that the order of $e$ is $1$ in all cases?

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The order of an element $g$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ so that $g^n = e $. In this case that's $1$.